# How do you manipulate html code which was created in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a problem with referencing newly created HTML which was created using JavaScript. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to access the newly created html for whatever reason. I've programmed the code to where I can display the numbers, but I cannot then manipulate them. Here is the code:

```js
let activ = document.querySelector("#fizbuz--btn");
0
let rever = document.querySelector("#fizbuz--btn1");
let displ = document.querySelector("#fizbuz--btn2");
let numbers = document.querySelector(".numbers")
let numberss = document.querySelectorAll(".num")

displ.addEventListener("click", () => {
  for (i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
    numbers.innerHTML += `<div class="num">${i}</div>`
  }
})

if (displ.clicked == true) {
  activ.addEventListener("click", () => {
    for (i = 0; i < numberss.length; i++) {
      if (numberss[i].innerHTML % 3 == 0 && numberss[i].innerHTML % 5 == 0) {
        numberss[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue"
      } else if (numberss[i].innerHTML % 3 == 0) {
        numberss[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
      } else if (numberss[i].innerHTML % 5 == 0) {
        numberss[i].style.backgroundColor = "orange"
      }
    }
  })

  rever.addEventListener("click", () => {
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      numbers[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(61, 133, 117)"
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-color">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="nav--head">Home</div>
    <div class="nav--head">About</div>
    <div class="nav--head">Contact</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="subHeading">
  This is just for practice. <br> This will be styled using CSS.
</div>

<div class="fbinfo">
  <div class="subhead">Multiples of 3 shall be highlighed in red</div>
  <div class="subhead">Multiples of 5 shall be highlighed in orange</div>
  <div class="subhead">Multiples of 3 and 5 shall be highlighed in blue</div>
</div>

<div class="fizbuzz">

  <div class="btns">
    <button id="fizbuz--btn2">Click Me for NUMBERS</button>
    <button id="fizbuz--btn">Click Me for FIZZBUZZ</button>
    <button id="fizbuz--btn1">Click Me for REVERSE</button>
  </div>

  <div class="numbers">
    <!-- <div class="num">1</div> <div class="num">2</div>
                <div class="num">3</div> <div class="num">4</div>
                <div class="num">5</div> <div class="num">6</div>
                <div class="num">7</div> <div class="num">8</div>
                <div class="num">9</div> <div class="num">10</div>
                <div class="num">11</div> <div class="num">12</div>
                <div class="num">13</div> <div class="num">14</div>
                <div class="num">15</div> <div class="num">16</div>
                <div class="num">17</div> <div class="num">18</div>
                <div class="num">19</div> <div class="num">20</div> -->
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: You're trying to iterate `numbers` in the click listener, but the collection is named as `numberss`.

Comment: You're calling `document.querySelectorAll(".num")` before you add those elements to the DOM. `document.querySelectorAll()` doesn't create a live nodelist, so adding the elements doesn't update the collection.

Comment: Buttons don't have a `clicked` property. so `if (displ.clicked == true)` will never succeed.

Comment: And even if buttons did have a `clicked` property, the code provided would never evaluate to `true` and add the event handlers as that expression would only be evaluated when the JS file was first executed (vs a `click` event causing the code to run later on).

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses, Unfortunately, I don't seem to understand what the solution to this is of yet. when I add the html code from javascript, do those elements get added to the DOM? If so, should I just call document.queryselectorAll(".num") after I have created the html elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign `numberss` *after* you add the elements to the DOM. So the assignment has to be in the click listener.

There's no `clicked` property on button elements, so `if (displ.clicked == true)` will never succeed and should be removed. You can add a check for whether the numbers have been created to the beginning of the other event listeners.

```js
let activ = document.querySelector("#fizbuz--btn");
let rever = document.querySelector("#fizbuz--btn1");
let displ = document.querySelector("#fizbuz--btn2");
let numbers = document.querySelector(".numbers")
let numberss;

displ.addEventListener("click", () => {
  for (i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
    numbers.innerHTML += `<div class="num">${i}</div>`
  }
  numberss = document.querySelectorAll(".num")
})

activ.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (!numberss) {
    alert("click on NUMBERS first");
    return;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < numberss.length; i++) {
    if (numberss[i].innerHTML % 3 == 0 && numberss[i].innerHTML % 5 == 0) {
      numberss[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue"
    } else if (numberss[i].innerHTML % 3 == 0) {
      numberss[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } else if (numberss[i].innerHTML % 5 == 0) {
      numberss[i].style.backgroundColor = "orange"
    }
  }
})

rever.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (!numberss) {
    alert("click on NUMBERS first");
    return;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < numberss.length; i++) {
    numberss[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(61, 133, 117)"
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="bg-color">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="nav--head">Home</div>
    <div class="nav--head">About</div>
    <div class="nav--head">Contact</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="subHeading">
  This is just for practice. <br> This will be styled using CSS.
</div>

<div class="fbinfo">
  <div class="subhead">Multiples of 3 shall be highlighed in red</div>
  <div class="subhead">Multiples of 5 shall be highlighed in orange</div>
  <div class="subhead">Multiples of 3 and 5 shall be highlighed in blue</div>
</div>

<div class="fizbuzz">

  <div class="btns">
    <button id="fizbuz--btn2">Click Me for NUMBERS</button>
    <button id="fizbuz--btn">Click Me for FIZZBUZZ</button>
    <button id="fizbuz--btn1">Click Me for REVERSE</button>
  </div>

  <div class="numbers">
    <!-- <div class="num">1</div> <div class="num">2</div>
                <div class="num">3</div> <div class="num">4</div>
                <div class="num">5</div> <div class="num">6</div>
                <div class="num">7</div> <div class="num">8</div>
                <div class="num">9</div> <div class="num">10</div>
                <div class="num">11</div> <div class="num">12</div>
                <div class="num">13</div> <div class="num">14</div>
                <div class="num">15</div> <div class="num">16</div>
                <div class="num">17</div> <div class="num">18</div>
                <div class="num">19</div> <div class="num">20</div> -->
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: haha, I love you my guy, I understand now. Thank you, your a real one.